# How to Polyfill node core modules using vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vite, esbuild

It seems that vite does not do automatic polyfills anymore - vite 4.0.0

How do you guys go about this? I have tried multiple variations of what I could find over the internet and none of them seems to be solid.

```
✘ [ERROR] The injected path "/Users/marian/code/OzoneV2/app-web/node_modules/@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill/_buffer.js" cannot be marked as external

✘ [ERROR] The injected path "/Users/marian/code/OzoneV2/app-web/node_modules/@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill/_virtual-process-polyfill_.js" cannot be marked as external

Build failed with 2 errors:
error: The injected path "/Users/marian/code/OzoneV2/app-web/node_modules/@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill/_buffer.js" cannot be marked as external
error: The injected path "/Users/marian/code/OzoneV2/app-web/node_modules/@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill/_virtual-process-polyfill_.js" cannot be marked as external
```

my config

```
// yarn add --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
// yarn add --dev @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
// You don't need to add this to deps, it's included by @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";

export default {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // This Rollup aliases are extracted from @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill,
            // see https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins/blob/master/node-modules-polyfill/src/polyfills.ts
            // process and buffer are excluded because already managed
            // by node-globals-polyfill
            util: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util",
            sys: "util",
            events: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events",
            stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
            path: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/path",
            querystring: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/qs",
            punycode: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/punycode",
            url: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/url",
            string_decoder: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/string-decoder",
            http: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http",
            https: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http",
            os: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/os",
            assert: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/assert",
            constants: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/constants",
            _stream_duplex: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/duplex",
            _stream_passthrough: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/passthrough",
            _stream_readable: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/readable",
            _stream_writable: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/writable",
            _stream_transform: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/readable-stream/transform",
            timers: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/timers",
            console: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/console",
            vm: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/vm",
            zlib: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib",
            tty: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty",
            domain: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/domain",
        },
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            // Enable esbuild polyfill plugins
            plugins: [
                NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
                NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
            ],
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [
                // Enable rollup polyfills plugin
                // used during production bundling
                rollupNodePolyFill(),
            ],
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the npm package [vite-plugin-node-polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills).

Install the package via `npm install --save-dev vite-plugin-node-polyfills`, then add the plugin to your `vite.config.ts` file.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
  ],
});
```

[See the package repo for full customisation options](https://github.com/davidmyersdev/vite-plugin-node-polyfills/blob/main/README.md): for example, you can also include only the polyfills that are relevant to your project.

```js
plugins: [
  nodePolyfills({ include: ['fs', 'stream'] }),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue "cannot be marked as external" when working with the bip39 package and getting error because of `buffer not defined`. I tried many stuffs so not sure how what I solved, but here is my configuration (working with svelteKit):

In vite.config.js:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import type { UserConfig } from 'vite';

const config: UserConfig = {
    plugins: [sveltekit()],

    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // polyfills
            Buffer: 'vite-compatible-readable-buffer',
            stream: 'vite-compatible-readable-stream',
            util: 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util',
        }
    }
};
export default config;
```

In layout.ts:

```
import { Buffer as BufferPolyfill } from 'buffer'
```

declare var Buffer: typeof BufferPolyfill;
globalThis.Buffer = BufferPolyfill

In app.html:

```
<script>
    /**
     * this is a hack for error: global is not defined
     */
    var global = global || window
</script>
```

I hope it helps. I'm new to svelte and I don't 100% know what I'm doing :p

Comment: `✘ [ERROR] Could not read from file: /home/projects/vitejs-vite-rm3gjc/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util

    node_modules/jws/lib/verify-stream.js:7:19:
      7 │ var util = require('util');` 

any idea why do I get this error?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-rm3gjc?file=vite.config.ts&terminal=dev

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills

Comment: the module is installed; same error

Comment: Strange because when I installed it in your stackblitz, it worked.

Sorry for late reply, I was on holiday. Let me know if you still need help